# How to implement coroutine dispatcher for java android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

So I was watching Android Developers channel on [how to build data layer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P125nWICYps&t=1144s) and at 19:18 I see him use the following code

```
val taskId = withContext(dispatcher){
    createTaskId()
}
```

Now given that

1. this code is written in kotlin
2. `dispatcher` is of `CoroutineDispatcher` data type
3. `createTaskId()` returns String
4. the code is implemented inside another suspend function

How can I **implement** this in **java** properly, or can I ?

Comment: It theoretically can be done, but it would be exceedingly complicated. The above would take about 15-20 lines of code in Java and you'd have to know exactly what you were doing with the low level coroutine continuations, so you'd have to be more of an expert on Kotlin coroutines than most highly competent Kotlin programmers. If you don't need to interact with Kotlin coroutine code, then you should use RxJava for this kind of thing.